# Linear Algebra Multiple Choice question. $A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix, consider $\{x,Ax,..A^5x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix with real entries. Consider the set $\{x,Ax, A^2x, A^3x, A^4x,A^5x\}$. What can we say about the set? Is it linearly independent or linearly dependent? When it would be Linear Independent?

**My Efforts**

First of all assume on the contrary that this set was linearly independent then It would contradict the fact that $\mathbb{R}^5$ has dimension $5$.

So this is set is linearly dependent.

**Further Analysis**

Now I have some question?

Is the set $\{x, A^2x, ..,A^4x\}$ linearly independent? I know it is not true for in general matrix as, if you take identity matrix, you get a contradiction.

So under what condition on $A$ this set become linearly independent?

Suppose $A$ is a general $n\times n$ matrix. Then I want to say something similar about $\{x,A^2x,...A^{n-1}x\}$.

Comment: You may want to look up the term "Krylov subspace". Basically, for "most" $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and "most" $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\{ x,Ax,\dots,A^{n-1} x \}$ is linearly independent. Exceptions among diagonalizable matrices occur when $A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$,$1$, or a root of unity and $x$ is an associated eigenvector. Exceptions among nondiagonalizable matrices can be a bit trickier.

Comment: Whenever the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $\boldsymbol A$ coincides [Wrong comment].

Comment: @xbh That's not true if $A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$ or $1$ or a root of unity and $x$ happens to be a suitable eigenvector.

Comment: The [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) tells you that for $\{x, \ldots,A^5x\}$, there is one linear depencence relation which will always hold, regardless of what $x$ is, and that's the one given by the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Apart from that, you may want to look into [minimal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)), which again gives a linear relation for a specific $A$ which _always_ holds, no matter what $x$ is, but may use fewer of the $A^kx$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I have missed something.

Comment: You have 6 vectors $\{ x,Ax,\cdots,A^5x \}$ is a five-dimensional space. So the set is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are considering is called a [cyclic subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace), and you want to know when the matrix $A$ has a *cyclic vector*, i.e., such that its cyclic subspace generates the whole vector space.

A matrix has a cyclic vector iff it is similar to the companion matrix of a polynomial; in general, a matrix is similar to a matrix formed by blocks by companion matrices (see [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form)), so you are asking for it to have only one such block.